# Intellij IDEA. Check syntax for files without extension

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, syntax-checking, goland

I have `Jenkinsfile` it's written in Groovy, but file name doesn't have approprite extension: `.groovy`. How can I tell IDEA to check groovy syntax of this file?

Update:
Also I interested in the same question about GoLand IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the project sidebar, right-click the file and choose "Associate with File Type". Then just select Groovy from the menu, and you're all set.

[image]

GoLand does not support Groovy so this will not be possible there.

Comment: I would upvote you ten times if I could. Game changer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you add following header comment in the beginning of your `Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
#!groovy
```

IntelliJ IDEA will automatically recognize this file as a Groovy source file. It should work for other editors and IDEs as well.